# How do I implement a lambda function inside a dict/set/list

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

So I am coding a user-input system that can accept commands. Further detail on it won't be revealed.

One of the things I want to do is implement a lambda function inside a dictionary.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
dictionary = {

   "command_a": lambda:

               stuff_to_do = ""
               # do stuff 
               return stuff_to_do
   
}
```

And when the user enters `command_a', it'd call the function, as follows:

```
command = input("Command")
if command in dictionary.keys():
  dictionary[command]()
```

But I get:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    stuff_to_do = ""
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code seems logical. The dictionary stores a function under the "command_a" key, but it doesn't work. Is it permissible to do so in python? If yes, then how to?

Comment: Also, by doing `dictionary[command]` you're not calling the function, but rather just accessing it.

Comment: @TomerAriel Yes true, I forgot the brackets. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @slothrop I know you can do that. But I want it do be a lambda function.

Comment: What functionality does the lambda function method have over just using a function?

Comment: Lambda is a single line statement. https://realpython.com/python-lambda/

Comment: @ElmatadorDeAngel sure - the value can be a lambda function, but of course it's subject to Python's restrictions on what a lambda can be.  `d = {"command_a": lambda: 42}` is fine for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `lambda` can only define a function in the form of a single expression, e.g.:

```
dictionary = {
   "command_a": (lambda: "stuff to do")
}
```

If you want to define a function that consists of multiple statements, you need to use a `def` statement:

```
def command_a():
    stuff_to_do = ""
    # do stuff 
    return stuff_to_do
   
dictionary = {
   "command_a": command_a
}
```